# iframe not showing in React Native WebView

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native, and for the first time learning about WebView, my iframe just shows as a blank screen. I try removing the iframe html and just putting `<h1>Hello</h1>` and it works. I'm sure I am missing something obvious.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      source={{
        html: `<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ss&ref=as_ss_li_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=lilbocheap0a-20&language=en_US&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B0157T1ZK2&asins=B0157T1ZK2&linkId=6cc99550e828f584b5cb20a067edf5f8&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true"></iframe>`,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: You are missing `https:` src attribute.

Comment: OH MY GOSH THAT WORKS. I feel so stupid but so happy that I'm grasping the concepts and just missed something so simple. A million thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `https` please add that to uri like this :

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      source={{
      html: `<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
      src="https://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ss&ref=as_ss_li_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=lilbocheap0a-20&language=en_US&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B0157T1ZK2&asins=B0157T1ZK2&linkId=6cc99550e828f584b5cb20a067edf5f8&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true"></iframe>`,
   }}
  />
 );
}
```